# Converting SOAP Response XML to JSON using XSJS

Tags: json, xml, sapui5, xsjs

I'm having problems to convert an XML response file to JSON using XSJS, Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: People would need more info than that to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple. While sending the request using XSJS to the server...your URL path should contain the format specifier.
http://myhost:8000/exampleapp/resource.xsjs/some/more/options?$format=JSON 
or if you do not want to append to the URL then include the following line your request header
**accept: application/json**